# Invoke javascript function in chrome tab from C# DLL

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome

As a part of migration from IE to Chrome of our website,
I have currently a C# dll which finding my IE instance and invoking javascript function in found web page
using IHTMLDocument2 and IHTMLWindow2 objects.

Now as my web page is opened in Chrome this option is not supported.

I found some examples of code how to find the tab in which my web page is opened but can't find any way how to invoke a function in there.

In my searches i found some suggestions but i can't find an adequate example of usage.

I understand that i will probably need to develop some kind of chrome extension but i don't understand how the communication will work between my dll and my web page.

Is there anyone who can direct me to a proper explanations and documentation about the process ?

Answer (score 0):

My dll is loaded in a Call Center program, when this program have event of receiving a call
the dll catches that event and need to pass customer information to load in my web page.

Comment: any suggestions ?